# Passing LONG queries to MySQLI through mysqli_query()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

so here's what I want to do, I want to be able to cache a whole web page, which would be something like this

```
$domain = "cnn.com"; 
$title = "CNN";
$cacheado = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');

$ingresar = "INSERT INTO indexed_links (link, title, cacheado) VALUES ('$domain', '$title', '$cacheado')";
$db_on = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'data_base');
mysqli_query($db_on, $ingresar);
```

My great concern is, I tried to do this exact code with the page example.com, which would be $cacheado = file_get_contents('http://example.com');

Which worked completely fine, it added the whole HTML code to the page, which is something somewhat short, it's an easy HTML code, now, Google and a bunch of other sites got more codes into their HTML, as a result, sites with longer HTML codes are not going through the mysqli_query query, which I suppose it has to do with MySql and not PHP because the code works just fine with example.com...

The column of the table which I want to insert the HTML code is cacheado, which has a type set in the MySQL database of text, does this have something to do?

Comment: If `$cacheado` happens to contain a single quote, MySQL can not make sense of your query. Read up on prepared statements.

Comment: If that was the case it wouldn't be able to process example.com or my localhost folder... but I tried your solution anyway and I wrote $cacheado = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");

Comment: If that was the case it wouldn't be able to process example.com or my localhost folder... but I tried your solution anyway and I wrote $cacheado = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com"); still not working

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. Imagine that the HTML you are trying to insert looks like `<body id='test'>Hello world</body>` – think what your `INSERT` query will look like in that case. The single quotes in the HTML will make your query text invalid, and MySQL will reject it. Again, read up on prepared statements and error handling.

Comment: Now I understand, you should have stated that it was the HTML code, I thought you were talking about the function parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the datatype.  Instead, you failed to escape the strings before building the INSERT statement.

In particular, there was probably an apostrophe (') in that web page.

Comment: ok, so what if I wanted to replace that (') with a double quotes (")? preg_replace or str_replace would be useful in this case?

Comment: Well, that was the issue, you've been a great help to me, I'll find a way to solve this issue now, thanks a lot mate.

Comment: PHP's addslashes() or real_escape_string() or something else, depending on the API you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Change field type from `TEXT()` to `VARCHAR(65535)`. It is the max lenght I now you can set for a field.

Comment: You can have fields of type `LONGTEXT` that can hold more than 65535 symbols.

Comment: Eh?  TEXT has a max length of 65K, just like that VARCHAR.  LONGTEXT is limited to 4GB.  MEDIUMTEXT is limited to 16MB.

Comment: I tried all options, all resulting in failure, apparently mysqli won't take my queries when the var $cacheado contains a web site with a really long HTML code, for a reason I tried with example.com and localhost, which contain really short html codes